# Ubuntu 12.04 & Nvidia 304 Causes Two Gnome-Panel

Tags: gnome, nvidia, multiple-monitors, gnome-panel, twinview

I just upgraded from Nvidia-curent to the 304 experimental so that I could install Steam. The 304 package is working just as well as the current driver on my setup except that when I log in I get two instances of gnome-panel on my primary monitor!

Its really odd as my settings are the same as they where in the current driver. (TwinView, absolute positioning on main monitor, 2nd is left of it) and I saved the xorg.conf over the old one instead of appending to it.

Any way to only get one instance of gnome-panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following, apparently gnome3 stores configuration in binary form.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Run: dconf-editor to edit the config.

Go to: org->gnome->gnome->panel->layout

The defaults are: (double click to edit)

```
object-id-list     ['menu-bar', 'indicators', 'show-desktop', 'window-list', 'workspace-switcher']
toplevel-id-list   ['top-panel', 'bottom-panel']
```

I found the answer on the "Related" collum on the right